# Redirect from client side and server side in nextJS

Tags: next.js, axios, next-connect

I am using next-connect to chain middleware inside the getServerSideProps and have the same set of middleware in the next JS API. I am calling the same using axios on client side.

How do I write a common logic in the middleware to redirect to another page.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried and didn't work ?

Comment: I tried 
1. res.writeHead(302, { location: '/Login' }) works with SSE but not axios.
2. res.status(403).json({
        status: 'Non-authenticated user.' }) and check for status code =403 on axios. But this does not work with SSE. I get an error like res.status is not a function